# User-arrangeable Android GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

So here's the thing, I want to build a **GridView containing few items that are movable/rearrangeable by the user**. Pretty much similiar as the one you'd see on the home screen of Android.

I've looked into some places but ended up with zero result. The closest thing I was able to find was the sample of a home screen app found on developers.android.com but It doesn't have the thing I'm looking for (the items are unarrangeable).

Please give me a hint how this could be done. Code examples are also welcome.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should implement a `drag&drop`.

The `GridView` can handle the `OnDragListener`, so you could do : `myGridView.setOnDragListener` and do whatever you want with it.

I also advise you to check the following [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)

I hope it helped!

Comment: Thank you so much! I haven't had any clue of such API even exist.

I still have one question in mind though. Inside the devloper page you gave me it says minimum API level of 11 is needed.

Now, what can I do if I want to make an application based on API 8 (Froyo)?